# Why $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4\sin\pi n}{\pi-\pi n^2}\sin nx=2\sin(x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I was using Wolfram Alpha to compute this integral
$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}2\sin x \sin nx \; dx=\frac{4\sin\pi n}{\pi-\pi n^2}$$

So if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ this answer must be $0$ right?

Then I used Wolfram Alpha again to compute
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4\sin\pi n}{\pi-\pi n^2}\sin nx$$
and it says 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4\sin\pi n}{\pi-\pi n^2}\sin nx=2\sin(x)$$
How is this possible?

Comment: "So if $n \in \mathbb Z$ this answer must be $0$ right?" - not if $n = \pm 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the first term in the sum is $$ \sin x \cdot \lim_{n\to1}\frac{4\sin \ \pi n}{\pi-\pi n^2} \\ \overset{\text{L.H.}}=4\sin x \cdot\ \lim_{n\to1} \frac{\cos \pi n\cdot \pi}{-2\pi n} \\ =2\sin x$$

The rest of the terms, as you say, will be zero.

Comment: Thank you so much!